# Why does this function give me a segmentation fault after its execution?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, c++17

Using `addElemento()` from the template class below gives me a segfault **immediatly after** its execution, and I can't understand why.

```
template <typename tipoT>
class Celula{
    private:
        tipoT elem;
        Celula *prox;
    public:
        Celula() { prox = nullptr; }
    friend class LinkedList<tipoT>;
};

template <typename tipoT>
class LinkedList{
    private:
        int tamanho;
        Celula<tipoT> *cabeca;
        Celula<tipoT> *ultima;
    public:
        LinkedList() : tamanho(0) { cabeca = new Celula<tipoT>(); ultima = cabeca; }
        ~LinkedList() { limpaLista(); delete cabeca; }
        int getTamanho() { return tamanho; }
        bool estaVazia() { return tamanho == 0; }
        tipoT *getElemento(int);
        void addElemento(tipoT); 
        void limpaLista();
};

template <typename tipoT>
void LinkedList<tipoT>::addElemento(tipoT novoElem){
    Celula<tipoT> *nova = new Celula<tipoT>();
    nova->elem = novoElem;
    ultima->prox = nova;
    ultima = nova;
    tamanho++;
}

template <typename tipoT>
tipoT *LinkedList<tipoT>::getElemento(int id){
    erroAssert(id > 0, "ID smaller or equal to zero");
    erroAssert(id <= tamanho, "ID bigger than size");

    Celula<tipoT> *aux = cabeca;

    for(int i = 0; i < id; ++i){
        erroAssert(aux != nullptr, "Null cell");
        aux = aux->prox;
    }
    return &aux->elem;
}
```

My test main:

```
int main(){
    LinkedList<int> *listaDeInts = new LinkedList<int>();
    cout << "Lista criada." << endl;
    listaDeInts->addElemento(20);
    cout << *listaDeInts->getElemento(1) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

that when executed, prints in the console:

> Lista criada. 
> Segmentation fault

`Celula` has no destructor, and `getElemento()` returns the item's address correctly. So why does the segfault happen? While debugging in gdb the execution stops as `addElemento()` ends, so I don't understand what's happening.

Comment: Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: Edited the post with actual code snippets. Yes, I've tried a debugger, and it stops the program as addElemento() ends. 
I assume getElemento() works properly because the segfault does not ocurr on repl.it, and the correct value prints. Going to add it either way

Comment: @user17732522 fixed the code and added getElemento's implementation. A lot of it is in portuguese though.

Comment: My guess would be that `ultima` is not pointing to a valid object, and therefore undefined behavior is invoked when `addElemento()` tries to dereference it.

Comment: If you are using the compiler gcc or clang, then I suggest that you compile with `-fsanitize=address,undefined` to add additional checks to determine whether you are doing something else that is wrong before the segmentation fault happens.

Comment: @Taekahn Yes, I debugged it with GDB. It stops as we exit ```addElemento()```, not even executing the next line, and returns the segfault.

Comment: The code is still not a [mre], but adding minimal code to make it work, I cannot reproduce any issue on compiler explorer. The UB sanitizer and address sanitizer don't see any problem. The only issue is that you are leaking memory, but that doesn't cause segmentation faults, see https://godbolt.org/z/nox11Worc. Please make sure to post _the whole code_ required for a [mre] and which you tested in that _exact_ form. The shown code is neither complete, minimal nor reproducible.

Comment: If you comment out the line after, does it crash? (Even though you said it doesn’t execute, that doesn’t guarantee that it isn’t the cause.

Comment: @Taekahn Executes just as normal, segfault and all.

Comment: @user17732522 I'll keep any other posts in the guidelines, thanks for the heads up. 
When I execute the code in an online enviroment it runs fine, but it gives me the segfault on VSCode.

Comment: In that case it sounds like a problem with your environment or your build steps. FWIW I see nothing in the code that should fault.

Comment: @user17732522 Understood. Thanks for the help! I'll try to find more about it and sort things out. Should I close the question?(Can I even do that? I'm new to posting here)

Comment: You said that you tried running your program in a debugger. On which platform did you run the debugger? On the platform on which the segmentation fault occurred or on a platform on which the code works? You should run the debugger on the platform on which the segmentation fault occurs. You should run your program line by line in the debugger, while monitoring the values of all variables, in order to determine at which point your program stops behaving as intended.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yeah, that's what I did: Ran GDB on VSCode, where the error occurs. Placed a breakpoint inside the function, ran it line by line while monitoring variables and it all worked, until leaving the function. That's why I'm stumped.

I'll try and find something about my enviroment causing this, as it seems more likely

Comment: @CalicoCat: So you are saying when you run the "s" command in GDB when you are on the line `tamanho++;` of the function `addElemento`, the segmentation fault occurs before GDB stops the program again in the calling function? Or are you using a different command?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Using "n" on the line ```tamanho++;``` It's equivalent to "next line", right?

Comment: @CalicoCat: Using "n" will not step into functions. I believe this means that it also won't step into constructors and destructors, but I am not sure. I suggest that you try using "s" instead of "n" to step into everything that is being executed, which could possibly cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Didn't know that. Will use "s", thanks for the heads up. I just compiled again to add fsanitize flags and the segfault just... didn't happen. It's 100% something in my enviroment. I will try to find and understand what.

Comment: @CalicoCat: Are you compiling with optimizations active? You should first try to reproduce the problem with optimizations off, as that is easier to debug.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel No, I'm not. I don't know much about it either

Comment: @CalicoCat: You are saying that you are unable to reproduce the segmentation fault with `-fsanitize=address,undefined` active. Did you take a look at the `stderr` output to determine whether the sanitizer provided an error message? Maybe it did not produce a segmentation fault because it found the error beforehand?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel  It does return memory leak errors. But thing is, since then, even compiling without ```-fsanitize=address,undefined``` doesn't reproduce the segmentation fault anymore.

Comment: @CalicoCat: Were you able to reliably reproduce the error beforehand? Then you must have changed someting, to make the error disappear.